# Reading traceID as B3 headers from Kafka payload using spring-kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring-kafka in my consumer application to read the records from kafka. The producer application is sending the B3 headers as follows.

```
ProducerRecord producerRecord = new ProducerRecord(kafkaTopic, key, timeOffRequestKafkaModel);
      producerRecord.headers()
          .add("X-B3-TraceId",tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

The consumer application is listening the records as follows using spring-kafka library

```
@KafkaListener(
            id = "foo",
            topics = "#{@kafkaConfig.getConsumerConfig('tor-consumers').getTopicName()}",
            groupId = "#{@kafkaConfig.getConsumerConfig('tor-consumers').getGroupId()}",
            concurrency = "#{@kafkaConfig.getConsumerConfig('tor-consumers').getConcurrency()}",
            containerFactory = "primaryKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            properties = "#{@kafkaConfig.getConsumerConfig('tor-consumers').getProperties()}"
    )
    public void onEvent(@Payload TimeOffRequestKafkaModel timeOffRequestKafkaPayload,
                                @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
                                @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset,
                                @Headers MessageHeaders headers,
                                Acknowledgment acknowledgment)
    {
        processTorEvent(timeOffRequestKafkaPayload, acknowledgment);
    }
```

I want to read the traceID and propagate it in my consumer application from B3 headers from kafka payload.

The dependencies spring-cloud-starter-sleuth is already added.

I configured the properties in my application.yml as follows but the sleuth generates its own traceId for each record consumed. What should I change so it can pick up the B3 header automatically and use it as the traceID for each records ?

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    propagation:
      type: B3
    messaging:
      kafka:
        enabled: true
      propagation:
        enabled : true
```

Comment: I think just `X-B3-TraceId` is not enough. You also need to propagate  `X-B3-ParentSpanId` and `X-B3-SpanId` values via headers: https://github.com/openzipkin/b3-propagation